# iOs simple hello, name not working

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I have recently started to learn Obj-C and Iphone development basically through Lynda.com iOs SDK essentials course. But it was written for Xcode 3.x and I have 4.0.x installed, so things are different.
Basically, I take example from there and it just doesn't work for me and I can't figure it out being a noob to it.

```
//basicViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface basicViewController : UIViewController {
IBOutlet UITextField *txtName;
IBOutlet UILabel *lblMessage;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *txtName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *lblMessage;

- (IBAction) doSomething;
@end
```

And my basicViewController.m

```
#import "basicViewController.h"

@implementation basicViewController
@synthesize txtName;
@synthesize lblMessage;

- (IBAction) doSomething
{
NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello, %@",txtName.text];
[lblMessage setText:msg];
[msg release];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
[super dealloc];
}
@end
```

I haven't changed basicAppDelegate.h and .m from what they were created like. I think I will post them anyway.

```
//
//  basicAppDelegate.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class basicViewController;

@interface basicAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
basicViewController *viewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet basicViewController *viewController;

@end


//
//  basicAppDelegate.m

#import "basicAppDelegate.h"
#import "basicViewController.h"

@implementation basicAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController;


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

// Override point for customization after app launch    
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
}


 - (void)dealloc {
[viewController release];
[window release];
[super dealloc];
}


 @end
```

And here's my main.m:

```
//
//  main.m


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

Also, on the Interface Builder window I have linked through File's Owner: label to lblMessage, TextField to txtName and doSomething to Button.

Now, the problem is: actually, the thing kinda works, only if I use the popup keyboard, not my physical one. And only if I type less than 3-4-5 symbols(differs sometimes).
If I use my keyboard, not the popping one - it gives me Thread 1 received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS.
Same if I type too many symbols.

And I don't see much in All Output - just some usual stuff, the only suspicious line is:

```
warning:unable to compile regular expression "dyld"
Current language: auto; currently objective-c
(gdb)
```

So, guys, any kind help is appreciated.

Comment: can try replacing the string format line with this and then remove the release two lines below?      NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello, %@",txtName.text];

Comment: Nothing changes, i could even leave the handler empty - it seems that the problem is while i'm typing the text into the textfield, i don't even press the button. The button works ok, so it seems...

Comment: Try running the app with NSZombieEnabled as environment variable and check the log output. Alt-click run the 'run' menu item and add `NSZombieEnabled` as `YES in the argument environment variables.

Comment: Hmm, nothing really changes. As far as i understand, Zombie would help me to solve two pointer problems, but i don't think that's what i have here. I have some additional lines like warning:unable to compile regular expression "dyld" and that's it. Btw, i got the backtrace popping up - of course - but there's so much stuff there...

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/oUFFU.png

Answer (score 1):

First, there didn't change something since Xcode 3 except the interface.

Try to set a breakpoint and look where you app is crashing...

Try to delete the IBOutlets and create it new...

Try to create a new app...

If all not works, take your Mac and throw it outside a window, bring it back to Apple. (or install Xcode again --> much cheaper..)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and spent AGES looking for the solution. I found out how to make it work and I've made a tutorial on how to make the Hello, Name  application on XCode. Take a look and see if it helps. I think if you follow the steps one by one you should have your app running in no time.

http://techtalktone.wordpress.com/2011/11/26/hello-world/

Hope this helps ;)